# How do I extract elements from json and into python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get the program to print "value", but it keeps giving me the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error message.

Json code:

```
[
  {
  "occupancy_pricing": {
    "2": {
      "nightly": [
        [ 
          { 
            "value": "13.20",
          },
          { 
            "value": "239.96",
          }
        ]
  }
]
```

Python code:

```py
for occupancy_price in json_data['occupancy_pricing']:
  print(occupancy_price)
  for t in occupancy_price['2']:
    print(t)
    for night in t['nightly']:
      print(night)
      for v in night['value']:
        print(v)
```

(json_data is the json file)

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Provide the full error message and output.

Comment: ```night``` is a list, not a dictionary, since ```t["nightly"]``` is a list of list.

Comment: The JSON *still* isn't valid.  Test it!  Show the code that loads it (`json_data = json.load(...)` for example) and show the error you get with your current code.  It's hard to solve a problem when the example breaks a different way.  We can guess like the current answer, but it stil may not represent your problem accurately.  Only you, the OP, know that.

Answer (score -1):

```
In [109]: a = {
     ...:     "occupancy_pricing": {
     ...:         "2": {
     ...:             "nightly": [
     ...:                 {
     ...:                     "value": "13.20"
     ...:                 },
     ...:                 {
     ...:                     "value": "239.96"
     ...:                 }
     ...:             ]
     ...:         }
     ...:     }
     ...: }

In [110]: [i["value"] for i in a["occupancy_pricing"]["2"]["nightly"]]
Out[110]: ['13.20', '239.96']
```

Comment: when I tried this it gave me a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` Error

Comment: @Dovski14 I corrected the json you attached. Can you paste the correct json in the question??